# How to extend the list of keywords for pygments.lexers.shell

Tags: syntax-highlighting, markdown, jekyll, pygments, github-pages

I am using [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) with [Pygments](http://pygments.org) to convert [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) to static html pages. The content is prepared for [GitHub pages](http://pages.github.com/). To display code samples (shell commands in this example) I add the following section to the files:

```
{% highlight sh %}
$ ls -1a
.
..
README
{% endhighlight %}
```

The parameter `sh` refers to shell which configures the lexer. You can also choose other lexers such as `console` for highlighting the text.

I noticed that some basic commands such as `ls` are not highlighted by the shell lexer. This can also be seen in the [source code of the lexer](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/f8f6f70f3ded/pygments/lexers/shell.py). The following excerpt show the keywords definition of the shell lexer (found in the BashLexer class).

```
...
'basic': [
    (r'\b(if|fi|else|while|do|done|for|then|return|function|case|'
     r'select|continue|until|esac|elif)\s*\b',
     Keyword),
    (r'\b(alias|bg|bind|break|builtin|caller|cd|command|compgen|'
     r'complete|declare|dirs|disown|echo|enable|eval|exec|exit|'
     r'export|false|fc|fg|getopts|hash|help|history|jobs|kill|let|'
     r'local|logout|popd|printf|pushd|pwd|read|readonly|set|shift|'
     r'shopt|source|suspend|test|time|times|trap|true|type|typeset|'
     r'ulimit|umask|unalias|unset|wait)\s*\b(?!\.)',
     Name.Builtin),
    (r'#.*\n', Comment),
    (r'\\[\w\W]', String.Escape),
    (r'(\b\w+)(\s*)(=)', bygroups(Name.Variable, Text, Operator)),
    (r'[\[\]{}()=]', Operator),
    (r'<<-?\s*(\'?)\\?(\w+)[\w\W]+?\2', String),
    (r'&&|\|\|', Operator),
],
...
```

Is there a way to extend the list of keywords or can you recommend another lexer instead?

Comment: You could have a look at the also popular [rainbow syntax highlighter](https://github.com/ccampbell/rainbow) instead. It's shell mode is demoed [here](http://htmlpreview.github.com/?https://raw.github.com/ccampbell/rainbow/master/demos/shell.html). It highlights `ls -1a` from what I've tried and should be easy to integrate.

Answer (score 4):

You can add keywords to a Pygments lexer by writing your own lexer that adds the new keywords, by subclassing another lexer. See the the [pygments doc](http://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment/) for more information. I've made a subclass'ed lexer that adds a couple of keywords to the C++ lexer, which can be seen in [this Github repo](https://github.com/FSund/pygments-custom-cpplexer).

I'm not sure how to add keywords of other types than `EXTRA_KEYWORDS`.

Comment: The `if` statement only checks whether the `value` is contained within the list defined by you, in this case `EXTRA_KEYWORDS`. You could create as many lists as you wish and create an `elif` branch for those as well, then `yield` the desired token instead of `Keyword`.